# Bamboo build plan fails with MS Test project

Tags: bitbucket, bamboo

I have a  .NET 4.6.1 solution that has a Class Library and a Unit Test project. I setup my build plan in Bamboo to do a Continuous Integration build. The build task fails with the below error.

> The type 'System.Attribute' is defined in an assembly that is not
>   referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.

I tried building this locally using Visual Studio and it builds just fine. I also tried building using MS Build on my developer laptop from the command line and it builds without any errors.

I removed the Unit Testing project from my solution and I got a successful build.

There is also a warning in one of the previous steps about .NET Framework 4.6.1. I believe this has nothing to do with the previous error, but I wanted to put everything out there just in case.

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(983,5):
>   warning MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" were not found. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
>   [D:\data\bamboo-agent-home\xml-data\build-dir\AIS-CTB-JOB1\Emc.Cryptography\Emc.Cryptography.csproj]

Comment: Well, does the bamboo server have 4.6.1 installed?

Comment: Yes. It does. I asked out infrastructure folks and they even uninstalled and re-installed it

Comment: That's bad. Next step is to turn on fusion logging and go see what's happening with the binder.

Comment: I am not sure what that is but thank you. I will run this by our folks here and see what they can do.

Comment: Just search "fusion logs" and you'll find out how it works. [edit] with details, or if you discover your answer, you can add it below and close this out.